# CSS animation of a background doesn't work in IOS

Tags: css, css-animations, slideshow

My slideshow does not work in iPhone. It does on Android and Windows.

Is there some mistake on my part?

```css
#slideshow  {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation: example 20s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: example 20s infinite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px; 
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;

}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/170781.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  25%  {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/169652.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  50%  {
    background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6zVp8ETUDU4/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  75%  {
    background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5oJbLGNj_uw/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/170781.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/170781.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  25%  {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/169652.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  50%  {
    background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6zVp8ETUDU4/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  75%  {
    background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5oJbLGNj_uw/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  100% {`enter code here`
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/170781.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow"></div>
```

Comment: in which ios version it's not working?

Comment: 11.4 ios version

Answer (score 0):

like `-webkit-animation-name` rewrite other properities like `animation-duration` and `animation-iteration-count` instead of shorthand notation.